# What is the valid java regex pattern for git branch?

Tags: java, regex, git, git-branch

I am trying to use github api in one of our application. This requires me to validate a branch name entered. Does anyone know what's a valid regex for github's branch names is?

Thanks,
Dinesh

Comment: what are you trying to do with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a call to [git-check-ref-format](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html)